# Symfony container: Definition not transformed into service

Tags: php, symfony

On a legacy application, we introduced the container in which we add `Definition` inside `Extension`

```
    $serviceId  = ($alias == 'default') ? 'm6_statsd' : 'm6_statsd.'.$alias;
    $definition = new Definition('M6Web\Component\Statsd\Client');
    $definition->setScope(ContainerInterface::SCOPE_CONTAINER);
    $definition->addArgument($usedServers);

    $container->setDefinition($serviceId, $definition);
```

// The method to compile container

```
private function loadContainer()
{
    // Ok that's just plain bad, but at least it works. I need this as a static because controllers can't access application
    // and I can't put container in models because it would be inherited by front office.
    self::$container = new ContainerBuilder();

    $helpscoutExtension = new HelpscoutExtension();
    self::$container->registerExtension($helpscoutExtension);
    self::$container->loadFromExtension($helpscoutExtension->getAlias());

    $statsdExtension = new StatsdExtension();
    self::$container->registerExtension($statsdExtension);
    self::$container->loadFromExtension($statsdExtension->getAlias());

    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(self::$container, new FileLocator(C_PATH_GLOBAL_CONF));
    $loader->load('bov6.yml');

    self::$container->compile();
    dump(self::$container);
}
```

The container is compiled but when I dump the container, it shows only the Definition and there are no services available

[image]

What am I missing please ? Why is the Definition not transformed into a service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't called the `$container->get('service')` method for a service, the service isn't created.

Service is instantiated the first time you try to access it.

Comment: You're right, thanks. As I was out of Symfony full stack, I was too cautius doing dumps everywhere and checked the container itself instead of the service.